# Loop with start and end indexes

Tags: python

I want to loop with an index that starts at 1 and ends at 3.

This is what I'm doing now:

```
for number in list(range(3)):
  print(number)
```

The output is:

```
0
1
2
```

What I want:

```
1
2
3
```

How can this be concisely done in Python?

Comment: Did you mean: `for number in range(1, 4):`?

Comment: The first stop should be the API - did you read the documentation of `range()`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range - what is your problem with the official documentation?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it attracts answers that just copy the official documentation for the range() function that the OP did not check.

Comment: This is almost a math problem. `print(number+1)` will work just fine here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give range start and end number, that is `range(start, end, step)`

```
start:- Optional. An integer number specifying at which position to start. Default is 0
end :- Required. An integer number specifying at which position to stop (not included).
step:-  Optional. An integer number specifying the incrementation. Default is 1

for number in list(range(1, 4)):
  print(number)
```

Comment: Please use code formatting for.... code

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this:

```
for number in range(1,4):
  print(number)
```

Note: the list(range(...)) is redundant. You don't need to pass the range iterator to the list constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This will work. The `range()` function has a `start` : Which number to begin with, then `stop` : at which number to stop, and `step` which means which how much increment.

```
for number in range(1,4):
  print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can easily specify the range for example `range(1,4)` will give you 1,2,3